# What is the minimum kinetic energy required for an electron to be confined in a nucleus?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, particle-physics, nuclear-physics

I have heard that there was a hypothesis that instead of neutrons inside the nucleus we could have thought about protons + electron pairs equal to the number of neutrons. i.e nucleus consists of 2Z number of protons and Z number of electrons inside the nucleus. A counter argument to this is that the Compton wavelength of electron is greater than the size of the nuclei.

If Compton wavelength $\frac{h}{mc}$ for a particle is constant then why I am finding questions asking "what is the minimum kinetic energy required for confining a relativistic electron inside a nucleus?". Does this mean Compton wavelength doesn't have anything to do with confining an electron inside a nucleus. Is it solely dependent on the kinetic energy of electron?

Comment: The hypothesis you're talking about predates wave mechanics. There never was a detailed model of how it could work.

Comment: Additionally, we know what an electron looks like when it is bound by protons. It looks like an electron in an atom.